# At Thrift Python server, how to configure the max threads in pool by using TThreadPoolServer?

Tags: python, thrift

I have a python service called by thrift. And I want to try **TThreadPoolServer** instead of **TThreadedServer**. After my trying, I found that TThreadPoolServer mod have lower cpu rate but lower speed. I guess the default max threads in pool is small. But i do not know how to configure this params in thrift python server. could anybody know about this? Thanks.

Comment: @VladislavMartin: Your sentence lacks some words  to make sense. My proposal would be to insert "*is limited*" before "*is correct*".

Comment: @JensG: Whoops! ... According to a GitHub user's analysis/benchmarking of Thrift's servers, your guess that the [maximum number of threads in the pool of `TThreadPoolServer` is limited](https://github.com/m1ch1/mapkeeper/wiki/TThreadedServer-vs.-TNonblockingServer#tthreadpoolserver-not-benchmarked-here) is correct. As was mentioned in @Arnial's answer, you can find in the source code that the default limit is equal to 10.

Answer (score 1):

See definitions in the source code, [TServer.py](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/0.9.3/lib/py/src/server/TServer.py).

The default number of threads in the pool of `TThreadPoolServer` is 10. See line 143 in the source code, under the definition of the `TThreadPoolServer` class.

You can change the number of threads in the pool by calling the following method: `TThreadPoolServer.setNumThreads(self, num)`.

UPDATE:

If your script needs more CPU than I/O, I recommend you to try using `TForkingServer`. It may work better then threaded server because of GIL.

From comments on lines 199-202 in the source code, under the definition of the `TForkingServer` class:

> A Thrift server that forks a new process for each request
>
> This is more scalable than the threaded server as it does not cause GIL contention.

Comment: Can you provide links in your answer to the documentation that you are referring to? In specific, a link to the source that states that the default max number of threads in the TThreadPoolServer is 10 *and* the TForkingServer docstring.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I do not find related api docs about thrift in web. May you give some advice about the related materials? Thank you again!

Comment: The default number of threads and docstring for `TForkingServer` i took from Thrift (v0.9.3) source codes. I added link to the file with definitions.

Comment: I don't know where to find good guide or api documentation for python.  Most of time when i need into about thrift internals, i just checking it source code.